# PWABuilder: How to remove "Done" button from the top of iOS PWA screen?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, pwabuilder

I'm trying to build iOS PWA with PWABuilder but the app has a "top panel" with useless "Done" button. It makes my app look very unprofessional. How to get rid of it? )))[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Check the `authOrigins` in your `Settings.swift` file. Any domain you add there will automatically open in the type of modal you are showing in the screenshot. Also, it seems that if you have an iframe on your page with one of these origins, the parent page will also be opened in a modal. As such, in your case, I'm guessing the issue may be caused by the way the login buttons are implemented.

If you believe the `authOrigins` shouldn't be causing the issue and you aren't using any iframes in your code, you should then also check any iframes added to your page by other libraries.